# Included source does not see types imported with use

Tags: macros, include, rust

I am struggling to include! some automatically generated code into a module.  My module looks like...

```
use libc::c_int;

mod nif_versions {
include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/nif_versions.snippet"));
}
```

... and nif_versions.snippet looks like ...

```
const NIF_MAJOR_VERSION: c_int = 2;
const NIF_MINOR_VERSION: c_int = 7;
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
/home/goertzen/ruster/target/build/ruster-7f1b6b5473eea720/out/nif_versions.snippet:1:26: 1:31 error: use of undeclared type name `c_int`
/home/goertzen/ruster/target/build/ruster-7f1b6b5473eea720/out/nif_versions.snippet:1 const NIF_MAJOR_VERSION: c_int = 2;
                                                                                                               ^~~~~
note: in expansion of include!
```

If I skip the include! and paste those 2 lines manually, everything works.  Also, I had to wrap the include in a module to make it work at all.  I would like to get rid of that if possible.

Comment: I was able to `include!` a file without a wrapper module. You may want to ask a second question if this continues to be a problem.

Comment: I tried the unwrapped include! and what do you know, it worked!  I must have had something else messing up compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to move `use libc::c_int` to the inner `mod` declaration because `use`s are only valid inside the module they are used:

```
mod nif_versions {
    use libc::c_int;
    include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/nif_versions.snippet"));
}
```

Comment: You may want to put the `use libc::c_int;` *into* the snippet as well, since it's more appropriately tied there...

Comment: Shepmaster:  That alone doesn't compile, but if I bring the module wrapper into the snippet then it *does* work.  I think I will do it that way and think of my snippets as fully self contained modules rather than fragments of code.